# How to send custom response using req.pipe in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I am using request module for video streaming. 
When response comes to browser ( google chrome ) plays the video with default html5 video player. But I, want to send the response to the custom player or to the "src" element of custom player which I have placed in jade or html file. How can I do so? 
this is code.

```
request(stream.url + '&signature=' + (stream.sig || stream.s)).pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http=require("http");
var request=require("request");
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){

//specify your url
if(req.url!=="/myvideo"){
    res.end();
    return;
}

//now you request a video
var url="something";
request(url)
    .on('data',function(chunk){
        //response data to your client
        res.write(chunk);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Now you can access your video by http://localhost:3000/myvideo